# Android Studio Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'

Tags: android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1 and I did was i renamed a working project with a new package. After that, I encountered the problem i mentioned above.

I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix this. I've tried adding the dependency files already. All of the solutions points to editing build.gradle file but I don't have that file because this project is imported from a eclipse project. Can anyone help me please?

Regards,
Dexter

Comment: check your style.xml file. I think Theme.AppCompat.Light is not present.

Comment: yup, i realize that but i don't know how to include the dependency. I've tried to add the appcompat_v7 to the project,go to open_module-settings->SDK->Classpath add the appcompat_v7 but still not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add dependency,follow the steps below.

```
1.file->new->Import Module.
after import module
2.file->Project Structure->app->dependency tab-> add library dependencies.
3.In build.gradle(your module) change to apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

if you get any error regarding min and target sdk versions, then choose 4th step other wise exclude 4th step(first 3 step enough).

```
4.file->Project Structure->example ->Flavors tab //change minimum and target sdk versions().
```

Comment: It still doesnt work. Perhaps anyone can just tell me how can i generate two different app with the same source? Maybe its easier? This is really ridiculous just simply change a package name give such a hassle.

Comment: check sdk build versions in build.gradle(compileSdkVersion ,
    buildToolsVersion )

Comment: i dont have a build.gradle file as this is not built from android studio. I imported this project.

Comment: is importing project eclipse or android?

Comment: the imported eclipse project is for android.